# How to save result of a query in variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to save result of a MYSQL query in variable. I know that results save as an array but I don't know how to assign result to variable.
I could echo result but I couldn't assign it to variable.

here is my code with error:

```
require('db.php');
$id =$_REQUEST['id'];
$name ="SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id='".$id."'";
$name_result = $con->query($name);
while($row = $name_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name=$row['name'];
    }
$ins_query=" insert into table1 (`id`,`name`) values ('$id','$name')";
$stat=mysqli_query($con,$ins_query) or die(" error".mysql_error());
```

Id gets from user as html input field and will save in table1.
Name exists in table2 and I want to select it where id in table1 is equals with id in table2 then insert it in table1.

Comment: 1. Provide the error. 2. Use prepared statements.

Comment: mysql_error() --> mysqli_error($con)

Comment: You use 3 different way for query. Therefore, it is not advisable to copy the code from different sources :)

Comment: Mind the possible SQL injection.. Also using `$_REQUEST` is bad security wise because the variable can come from the url (get data), post data or cookie data i strongly advice against using `$_REQUEST` and use `$_GET` or `$_POST` to get the variables..

Comment: where $con is defined ?

Comment: *"it is not advisable to copy the code from different sources"* indeed @Gabor that is the best advice i've heard today.. That is the very much the problem nowadays on the internet and programmers which copy and paste code from old outdated tutorials into production code without thinking futher if the code might have vulnerabilities and modify it to make it safe and or how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $name ="SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id='$id'";
```

As you said that we can store variables as arrays

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($name))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

So after that $array[] will have the value that you want but if you want to have single variable instead of an array you can convert it by using equivalent. I hope that this one helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```js
require('db.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
//modification
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $id);
$query->execute();
//assuming you are retrieving only 1 value
$result = $query->get_result->fetch_assoc();

if ($result) {
  //value stored...use as you wish!
  $name = $result["name"];

} //you can add your else
```

**$this->db is your db connection**

Comment: I think it is obvious when someone down votes an answer, he/she could at least explain their action.